# Odd tags... well, rather keyboard keys tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I've found a couple of odd tags, starting with [alt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/alt) which I believe would have more sense if used [keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) instead (yeah, 101 tags for each key in the keyboard is overkill) but the funny thing is that it's also a html attribute, so both on topic, both could be misused. Same with [tabs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tabs), seems that is used for Tabulation key **and** tabs of [tabbed document interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_%28GUI%29). So, what to do with 'em?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[alt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/alt) is a terrible tag. Equally [tabs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tabs) is a terrible tag for either definition (keyboard or GUI). Both should likely be killed off as they are, in my opinion, dreaded [META tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: Added to the trello board https://trello.com/c/CsFnouLD