# Numlock, capslock and led tag (I'm surprised I didn't find PrntScr... yet)

Tags: discussion, tags

Trogdor must be fed with these:

- [numlock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/numlock)
- [capslock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/capslock)
- [key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/key)
- <strike>[led](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/led) - **DONE**</strike>
- [something](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/something) (this one still does not exist, *still*)

More to the list:

- [corruption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/corruption)
- [mp3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mp3) / [mp3-tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mp3-tag) (irony?)
- [files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/files)
- money [transfer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/transfer)
- [music](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/music) -> [music-player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/music-player) when applicable
- [mute](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mute)
- [capture](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/capture)
- [sniffing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sniffing) (srly?) - No more
- we need [order](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/order) with the tags!
- <strike>[touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/touch) ing? Look, but no touch!</strike>
- [minimal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/minimal) understanding how all these tags were created in the first place.

BTW, do all these tags now that Oli isn't here MUHAHAHAHA!

Comment: So.. is this a burniation request or a blacklist request? We don't normally blacklist tags unless they keep appearing after we kill them (like [tag:crash] (*hint hint* to any mods reading this))

Comment: @Seth meh, is a call that if you see that tag somewhere, please remove them.

Comment: Okay.. so who is going to do the dirty work?

Comment: I do... whenever I have the time, but a couple of extra hands are always welcomed :D

Comment: I agree with the muahaha part.

Comment: What's wrong with numlock and capslock? I can't work if your goal is to slowly delete all the tags or just annoy me, but these two are examples of good tags. The others are all a bit more fishy. Touch and Minimal should probably be linked to Ubuntu-Touch and Ubuntu-Minimal...

Comment: @Oli ok, lets create a tag for the print screen key, a tag for each of the function buttons, catch the drift? The relevance of the tags is null compared to xorg, keyboard, etc. Is the same as [alt and tab tags](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7537/169736) that only describe a question superficially (something related to a keyboard key) without the identifying with wild guesses underlying issue.

Comment: To put it in practical terms: polkit and gnome-screensaver ignores my numlock preferences and let the numpad behave like arrows keys, etc. What tag should I use? numlock or polkit/gnome-screensaver tags? Which is more *relevant*? (This is an actual problem that I still haven't feel annoyed enough to ask a question about it)

Comment: @Braiam All three! That's the point of tags... They're supposed to describe the key parts of the problem.

Comment: @Oli sorry, but that's madness. They don't represent any "topic" nor any well defined "category". Please, show me a case where the tag *alone* will be relevant and I will leave the tag, otherwise is not up to the site quality standards and should be removed (please note that I've stopped removing those tags until we sort out this, or would you rather start a separated meta post for those specific tags?).

Comment: @Braiam I'm in the middle of writing a meta post to serve as a FAQ on tags but wanted to just say that in this last example, "numlock" is completely relevant because it's part of the problem. Tags aren't just big topics like "things you might find a book about" and as I say, you're not limited to one. Pick the five most relevant things.

Comment: @Oli this seems relevant http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213751/213575

Comment: @Braiam Not with this example, no, not really. The numlock status is the core problem you're trying to fix.

Comment: I guess num-lock and caps-lock might be ok tags..